# Does Test.setCreatedDate work on ContentDocument?

Tags: apex, contentdocument

I wrote a trigger that checks if a contentdocument is greater than 10 minutes old, then throws an error to stop it from being deleted. This is to allow users to delete the file if they accidently upload the wrong but but keeps it if it's been around.

Now I'm writing a test class to test the logic and I'm trying to set the createdDate to be older than now so that I can catch the error message. However, when I try to set the time back in the createddate it still asserts the same time.

Example:

```
@isTest static void testdelete_errormessage()
{
    ContentVersion newFile = new ContentVersion();
        newFile.PathOnClient = 'TestFile';
        newFile.Title = 'DANTest';
        newFile.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('sample content');
    insert newFile;
    
    ContentDocument example = [SELECT Id, createddate, systemmodstamp FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title = 'DANTest'];
    String actualError;
    
    System.debug('createdDate:: ' + example.CreatedDate);
    System.debug('systemmodstamp:: ' + example.SystemModstamp);
    
    Test.setCreatedDate(example.Id, System.now().adddays(-1));
    
    System.debug('createdDate:: ' + example.CreatedDate);
    System.debug('systemmodstamp:: ' + example.SystemModstamp);
    
    test.startTest();
        try{
            delete example; 
        } catch(DMLException e)
        {
            actualError = e.getMessage();
        }
    test.stopTest();
    
    System.debug('actualerror:: ' + actualError);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, actualError,
        'The file delete should error');
}
```

When I look at the log when running the test the createddate and systemmodstamp are the same before and after doing Test.setCreatedDate.

My question is, does setCreatedDate not work on files or am I writing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do setCreatedDate you have to re-query the SObject to see the change. Thus the revised test method would look like this:

```
@isTest static void testdelete_errormessage()
{
    ContentVersion newFile = new ContentVersion();
        newFile.PathOnClient = 'TestFile';
        newFile.Title = 'DANTest';
        newFile.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('sample content');
    insert newFile;
    
    ContentDocument docv1 = [SELECT Id,createddate, systemmodstamp FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title = 'DANTest'];
    String actualError;
    
    System.debug('createdDate:: ' + docv1.CreatedDate);
    System.debug('systemmodstamp:: ' + docv1.SystemModstamp);
    
    Test.setCreatedDate(docv1.Id, System.now().adddays(-1));
    
    ContentDocument docv2 = [SELECT Id,createddate, systemmodstamp FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title = 'DANTest'];
    
    System.debug('createdDate:: ' + docv2.CreatedDate);
    System.debug('systemmodstamp:: ' + docv2.SystemModstamp);
    
    test.startTest();
        try{
            delete docv2; 
        } catch(DMLException e)
        {
            actualError = e.getMessage();
        }
    test.stopTest();
    
    System.debug('actualerror:: ' + actualError);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, actualError,
        'The file delete should not error');
```